# Render multiline text with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, text, render, multiline

I'd like to render multiline text in Rails, the action looks like:

```
def mutli_text
  render :text => 'Word1\nWord2'
end
```

and I'd expect the response to be :

```
Word1
Word2
```

unfortunatly I get Word1\nWord2

Any help would be appreciated

(The action must render a multiline response to get the autocomplete jquery plugin working)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
"Word1\nWord2"
```

You have to use double quotes to be able to use escaped characters.

But if you want to have that actually be a line break in the browser, you need to make it an actual html tag.

```
'Word1<br/>Word2'
```

Or even:

```
"Word1<br/>\nWord2"
```

Answer (score 3):

you can actually do something like this:

`(render :text => "line1\nline2").gsub("\n",'<br />')`

It at least works on #render within a view (using HAML). I haven't tried it within a controller action.

Answer (score 0):

Just render the text as `plain`. You can even change the content type to csv if you want to.

```
render :plain => 'Word1\nWord2', :content_type => "text/csv"
```